# GraphQL Query Format Issue

Tags: express, graphql

Im new to GraphQL, JS and backend in general. Im trying to make a query to the BE demo im trying, but i cant get it to pass, i assume this is a syntax missunderstanding...

The func looks like:

```
Mutation: {
  createUser: async (parent, { user }, context, info) => {
    const newUser = await new User({
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      age: user.age
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      newUser.save((err, res) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);
      });
    });
  },
```

and my query looks like:

```
mutation createUser(user: $user) {
  name,
  _id
}
```

with a var property of:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jack"
  }
}
```

my understanding would be that the mutation wants to take a user object, so i send the user query passing in the $user var?

Appreciate some help with what im not understanding here!

Comment: All you specify is that you "can't get it to pass", so it's unclear from this question what is actually wrong. When writing these types of questions, it's helpful to include what errors, if any, you are seeing. If there is an expected behavior you're not seeing, it's helpful to describe that and the actual behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows the `mutation` keyword is the name for your operation, which is arbitrary and could even be omitted outright. You still need to actually identify which field or fields on the Mutation type you are querying. In this case, the field we want is `createUser`, so we need to do something like this:

```
mutation SomeName ($user: UserInput) { 
  createUser(user: $user) {
    name,
    _id
  }
}
```

Notice that we have to also define our variables in the first line. Then we can use those variables anywhere in our query. Also note that, based on your question, I have no idea what the type for `$user` would actually be -- you'll need to change `UserInput` to match your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be something like this:

```
Mutation: {
  createUser(user, context, info) => {
    const newUser = await new User({
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email
      age: user.age
    });

    return Promise.resolve()
      .then((data) => {
        newUser.save(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I don' know about your schemas in detail, If you make your schema like this(email required, age required):

```
type User{
  _id:ID!
  name:String!
  email:String!
  age:Int!
}
```

then you should pass email, age info in your mutation parameter.

and seems like using mongoose. Then you can code like this:

```
Mutation: {
  createUser: async (parent, { user }, context, info) => {
    const newUser = await new User({
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    age: user.age
  });

  const result = newUser.save()

  return {...result._doc, id:result.id}
},
```